# Le eco le 2 Android 6.0 : How to share my computer internet on my android with USB?

Tags: rooting, adb, usb-debugging, reverse-tether, superuser

Having troubles sharing my internet connection from my desktop computer to my LE ECO LE 2 compact phone. I went to Settings -> Network connections -> USB connection. From this post (a bit old, it's meant for KitKat and not Marshmallow), I expected to view an option like USB internet. But there is only an option called Software install that I checked. But what software is this option about and how to install it, I don't get it.

I tried to connect my phone to my Windows 10 computer after checking the option, nothing special comes, no software install. I can choose several options :

charging only
transfer files (MTP)
mass storage (MSC)
MIDI
Choosing MTP, I can move files from my computer to my phone. But unlike what is presented in this post, no additional network connection do appear on my computer. I tried to share my connection (because my computer have two Ethernet ports, I can activate it anyway), but that does not work. No internet on my phone.

Sorry if the menus or options from this post are not strictly the same in the english version, my phone is in another language. Anyway, What I describe should be clear enough (otherwise just say, I'll explain more deeply).

Can anyone help ? I guess it's something special to Sony phones, or maybe it did change from Android 4 to Android 6, but I'm a little confused...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, only a few manufacturers include the USB Internet option in the menu.

I was looking for a way to reverse tether my Android devices some time ago as well and eventually developed my own solution. The result is an app that works on devices running Android 4.0 or higher on client side, and all major desktop OSs on the host side.

[image: The ReverseTethering NoRoot app]

The app is available on Google Play: [ReverseTethering NoRoot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.reversetethering.free)